# Running website on node js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, express, vps

I want to access my node app from my base url path, `example.com` so I set my listening port to 80 inside my `app.js` file with express js.

Below is my `app.js` file. Credit: [node static site tutorial](http://www.fullstacktraining.com/articles/how-to-serve-static-files-with-express).

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

// Define the port to run on
app.set('port', 80);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Listen for requests
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
});
```

I start my server with `node app.js` and can access my content as intended - but as soon as my connection is closed, my site is inaccessible. This is my first time experimenting with a non LAMP solution.

How can I keep my node server running on the cloud to serve my website? Is this what we call "deploying node to production?".

This is just a personal site with some static html / js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close the connection, you close the shell session you started node in.

Since you are running it in linux, simplest method is to run it in background `node app.js &`

Or you can install **screen** for a terminal which will stay running & can be detached from your current session. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/

Also, In case of unhandled errors in your code, servers programs can crash. To keep the server running & restarting when crashed use nodemon or [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

Comment: That's awesome - I chose your first option for simplicity. And this is normal? Nothing too unsafe about leaving a node server running indefinitely on your VPS to serve a simple portfolio site to the public?

Comment: not really, If it's just serving static files, but as I said the first option is prone to crash & not restart automatically.